# Listview items show they've been clicked when they haven't

Tags: java, android, listview

Hey so i've got a listview with buttons on it, when one is clicked if you skip down 4 more listview items the fifth shows it's been clicked in the same place the previous one was clicked. When a button is clicked it is set to invisible and the dummy button underneath is shown (which is the one that shows up in every fifth row).
Code that declares button invisible in the onclick command

> boolean processClick=true;

```
    if(processClick == true)
     {
        myButton.setEnabled(false);
        myButton.setClickable(false);
        myButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



        }
        processClick=false; 
        }
```

After looking at some similar questions, I think this has to do with the views being recycled, but still not sure how to remedy this.

Any helps at all is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes u are having problem with your code,you need to take processClick for each listView row/item and then on that bases u need to set enabled(false) or something else.You can take reference from this example which is similar work but with checkbox. You need to look at that code and apply with button. It'll solve your problem.

link of sample ex. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6C9Pqrvc_CWZHFDcmxKR01rc3c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem when I was programatically assigning background color to my listview items. I dont know what caused the problem (probably the getView() was not getting called properly). I solved my problem by using if-else. In your case something like this should work:

```
if(processClick == true)
 {//set desired result in if
    myButton.setEnabled(false);
    myButton.setClickable(false);
    myButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }else{//reset items to original in else
    myButton.setEnabled(true);
    myButton.setClickable(true);
    myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: This code definitely seems to work better, however now it skips 6 listview items and shows the 7th as being pressed. It definitely is an odd problem, I think I may just need to end up storing clicks in a DB.

Comment: may be you are selecting wrong position due to array index starting at zero but the size would be last position+1. I observed this when I was extending baseadapter for my custom adapter. ArrayAdapter<T> doesnot give this problem I guess.

Comment: Yea im using a base adapter, thanks for your response i'll look in to this, I also just noticed if it's the first item of the listview this doesn't happen at all oddly enough. However, 2nd and 3rd ranked items it still occurs.